# Same function twice only works once

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I can't find the solution although I'm sure there is one. I use post__not_in. But I need it twice in my functions.php (Wordpress). If I use the first one only, it works. If I use the second one only, it works, too. But if I use both, the second post__not_in gets ignored. The functions rest works like a charm. I'm sure to most of you this is completely clear. I am getting crazy about it. Do you have an Idea to share? Best regards and thank you so much!

```
function wpb_postsbycategory2() {
// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post__not_in'=>array(get_the_ID()),
    'category_name' => 'news', 
    'posts_per_page' => 1
) ); 
    

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post(); { 
            $string .= '<div class="block inline-group " data-widget-id="inline-group-0-no-images">
<ul><li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_title() .'</a></li></ul></div></div>';
        }
    }
}

    
return $string;
    
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
}

add_shortcode('categoryposts2', 'wpb_postsbycategory2');

add_action('inline_group_0', function () {
    echo do_shortcode('[SHORTCODE2]');
}, 10);


// SECOND USAGE
function wpb_postsbycategory() {
// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post__not_in'=>array(get_the_ID()),
    'category_name' => 'news', 
    'posts_per_page' => 2
) ); 
    

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $string .= '<ul class="result-grid desktop-2 mobile-2">';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            $string .= '<li><div class="recoinc">';
            $string .= '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, array( 450, 300) ) . get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
            } else { 
            // if no featured image is found
            $string .= '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
            }
            }
    } else {
    // no posts found
 $string .= '';
}
$string .= '</ul>';
    
return $string;
    
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
}
// Add a shortcode
add_shortcode('categoryposts', 'wpb_postsbycategory');

add_action('after_feed_block_0', function () {
    echo do_shortcode('[SHORTCODE1]');
}, 20);
```

Comment: `wp_reset_postdata();` before your return code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you have added reset post data at wrong place that part of code never gets executed.

```
function wpb_postsbycategory2() {
// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
'post__not_in'=>array(get_the_ID()),
'category_name' => 'news',
'posts_per_page' => 1
) );


if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
$the_query->the_post(); {
$string .= '<div class="block inline-group " data-widget-id="inline-group-0-no-images">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_title() .'</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>';
}
}
}

/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
return $string;


}

add_shortcode('categoryposts2', 'wpb_postsbycategory2');

add_action('inline_group_0', function () {
echo do_shortcode('[SHORTCODE2]');
}, 10);


// SECOND USAGE
function wpb_postsbycategory() {
// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
'post__not_in'=>array(get_the_ID()),
'category_name' => 'news',
'posts_per_page' => 2
) );


if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
$string .= '<ul class="result-grid desktop-2 mobile-2">';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    $string .= '<li>
        <div class="recoinc">';
            $string .= '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, array( 450, 300) ) . get_the_title() .'</a>
    </li>';
    } else {
    // if no featured image is found
    $string .= '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
    }
    }
    } else {
    // no posts found
    $string .= '';
    }
    $string .= '</ul>';
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
return $string;


}
// Add a shortcode
add_shortcode('categoryposts', 'wpb_postsbycategory');

add_action('after_feed_block_0', function () {
echo do_shortcode('[SHORTCODE1]');
}, 20);
```

Comment: Oh damn, that's it. And I didn't see it. Thank you so much. You made my day, Rikesh!